# jQuery UI: DatePicker ONLY CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, accordion

I'm using both the jQuery UI accordion and the datepicker.

The accordion works great, but when I add the CSS file to the page (which is needed by the datepicker), everything goes nuts. I see that the script adds all kinds of classes to both widgets. Is there any way to get a separate CSS that only works for the datepicker? I tried downloading different files from their site, but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post some *simple* example code?  or maybe a link to the problemed page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.  Using the jquery UI themeroller `scope`.

In the right hand column of the [download section](http://jqueryui.com/download) (under the theme drop-down menu) There is a link to open the advanced menu.  The value you input for the scope can be a custom class - such as `.ui-stylized` or whatever you class you want the css to apply to.  You can even mix and match entire themes if you'd like.

I would recommend using the themeroller to modify any jquery ui specific CSS.

Cheers!

Comment: Does not work, I tried using the scope, it does not work.

Answer (score 26):

Datepicker only (jquery.ui.datepicker.css):

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI Datepicker 1.9.0
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#theming
 */
.ui-datepicker {
    display: none;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    width: 17em;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
    padding: .2em 0;
    position: relative;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    height: 1.8em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 1.8em;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { top: 1px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev { left: 2px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { right: 2px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover { left: 1px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover { right: 1px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
    line-height: 1.8em;
    margin: 0 2.3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1px 0;
}

.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year { width: 100%; }

.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year { width: 49%; }

.ui-datepicker table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 0 0 .4em;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .7em .3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1px;
}

.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    display: block;
    padding: .2em;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    margin: .7em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 .2em;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: .5em .2em .4em;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em;
    width: auto;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current { float: left; }

/* with multiple calendars */

.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi { width: auto; }

.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group { float: left; }

.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
    margin: 0 auto .4em;
    width: 95%;
}

.ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 50%; }

.ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 33.3%; }

.ui-datepicker-multi-4 .ui-datepicker-group { width: 25%; }

.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width: 0; }

.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header { border-left-width: 0; }

.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { clear: left; }

.ui-datepicker-row-break {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0em;
    width: 100%;
}

/* RTL support */

.ui-datepicker-rtl { direction: rtl; }

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev {
    left: auto;
    right: 2px;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next {
    left: 2px;
    right: auto;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev:hover {
    left: auto;
    right: 1px;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next:hover {
    left: 1px;
    right: auto;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane { clear: right; }

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button { float: left; }

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current { float: right; }

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group { float: right; }

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0;
}

/* IE6 IFRAME FIX (taken from datepicker 1.5.3 */

.ui-datepicker-cover {
    filter: mask(); /*must have*/
    height: 200px; /*must have*/
    left: -4px; /*must have*/
    position: absolute; /*must have*/
    top: -4px; /*must have*/
    width: 200px; /*must have*/
    z-index: -1; /*must have*/
}
```

Accordion only (jquery.ui.accordion.css):

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI Accordion 1.9.0
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#theming
 */
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons { padding-left: 2.2em; }

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-noicons { padding-left: .7em; }

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons { padding-left: 2.2em; }

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    left: .5em;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

You'll also need the base theme (jquery.ui.theme.css):

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.9.0
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API
 *
 * To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
 */


/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/

.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
}

.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }

.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    background: #ffffff /*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) /*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50% /*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/;
    color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;
}

.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/; }

.ui-widget-header {
    background: #cccccc /*{bgColorHeader}*/ url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png) /*{bgImgUrlHeader}*/ 50% /*{bgHeaderXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgHeaderYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHeaderRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorHeader}*/;
    color: #222222/*{fcHeader}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-widget-header a { color: #222222/*{fcHeader}*/; }

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: #e6e6e6 /*{bgColorDefault}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) /*{bgImgUrlDefault}*/ 50% /*{bgDefaultXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgDefaultYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgDefaultRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3/*{borderColorDefault}*/;
    color: #555555/*{fcDefault}*/;
    font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
}

.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited {
    color: #555555/*{fcDefault}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background: #dadada /*{bgColorHover}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png) /*{bgImgUrlHover}*/ 50% /*{bgHoverXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgHoverYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHoverRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #999999/*{borderColorHover}*/;
    color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/;
    font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
}

.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover {
    color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
    background: #ffffff /*{bgColorActive}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png) /*{bgImgUrlActive}*/ 50% /*{bgActiveXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgActiveYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgActiveRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorActive}*/;
    color: #212121/*{fcActive}*/;
    font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
}

.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #212121/*{fcActive}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/

.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    background: #fbf9ee /*{bgColorHighlight}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png) /*{bgImgUrlHighlight}*/ 50% /*{bgHighlightXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgHighlightYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHighlightRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #fcefa1/*{borderColorHighlight}*/;
    color: #363636/*{fcHighlight}*/;
}

.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a { color: #363636/*{fcHighlight}*/; }

.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
    background: #fef1ec /*{bgColorError}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png) /*{bgImgUrlError}*/ 50% /*{bgErrorXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgErrorYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgErrorRepeat}*/;
    border: 1px solid #cd0a0a/*{borderColorError}*/;
    color: #cd0a0a/*{fcError}*/;
}

.ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a { color: #cd0a0a/*{fcError}*/; }

.ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text { color: #cd0a0a/*{fcError}*/; }

.ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary { font-weight: bold; }

.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary {
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: .7;
}

.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
    background-image: none;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=35);
    opacity: .35;
}

/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */

.ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }

.ui-widget-header .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsHeader}*/; }

.ui-state-default .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)/*{iconsDefault}*/; }

.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsHover}*/; }

.ui-state-active .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsActive}*/; }

.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png)/*{iconsHighlight}*/; }

.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png)/*{iconsError}*/; }

/* positioning */

.ui-icon-carat-1-n { background-position: 0 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-ne { background-position: -16px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-e { background-position: -32px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-se { background-position: -48px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-s { background-position: -64px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-sw { background-position: -80px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-w { background-position: -96px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-1-nw { background-position: -112px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s { background-position: -128px 0; }

.ui-icon-carat-2-e-w { background-position: -144px 0; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-n { background-position: 0 -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-ne { background-position: -16px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-e { background-position: -32px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-se { background-position: -48px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-s { background-position: -64px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-sw { background-position: -80px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-w { background-position: -96px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-1-nw { background-position: -112px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -16px; }

.ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w { background-position: -144px -16px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-n { background-position: 0 -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-ne { background-position: -16px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-e { background-position: -32px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-se { background-position: -48px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-s { background-position: -64px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-sw { background-position: -80px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-w { background-position: -96px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-1-nw { background-position: -112px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -32px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n { background-position: 0 -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne { background-position: -16px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se { background-position: -48px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s { background-position: -64px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw { background-position: -80px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w { background-position: -96px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw { background-position: -112px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -48px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w { background-position: 0 -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n { background-position: -16px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s { background-position: -48px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w { background-position: -64px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n { background-position: -80px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e { background-position: -96px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s { background-position: -112px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w { background-position: -128px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n { background-position: -144px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e { background-position: -160px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -176px -64px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-4 { background-position: 0 -80px; }

.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag { background-position: -16px -80px; }

.ui-icon-extlink { background-position: -32px -80px; }

.ui-icon-newwin { background-position: -48px -80px; }

.ui-icon-refresh { background-position: -64px -80px; }

.ui-icon-shuffle { background-position: -80px -80px; }

.ui-icon-transfer-e-w { background-position: -96px -80px; }

.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w { background-position: -112px -80px; }

.ui-icon-folder-collapsed { background-position: 0 -96px; }

.ui-icon-folder-open { background-position: -16px -96px; }

.ui-icon-document { background-position: -32px -96px; }

.ui-icon-document-b { background-position: -48px -96px; }

.ui-icon-note { background-position: -64px -96px; }

.ui-icon-mail-closed { background-position: -80px -96px; }

.ui-icon-mail-open { background-position: -96px -96px; }

.ui-icon-suitcase { background-position: -112px -96px; }

.ui-icon-comment { background-position: -128px -96px; }

.ui-icon-person { background-position: -144px -96px; }

.ui-icon-print { background-position: -160px -96px; }

.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -176px -96px; }

.ui-icon-locked { background-position: -192px -96px; }

.ui-icon-unlocked { background-position: -208px -96px; }

.ui-icon-bookmark { background-position: -224px -96px; }

.ui-icon-tag { background-position: -240px -96px; }

.ui-icon-home { background-position: 0 -112px; }

.ui-icon-flag { background-position: -16px -112px; }

.ui-icon-calendar { background-position: -32px -112px; }

.ui-icon-cart { background-position: -48px -112px; }

.ui-icon-pencil { background-position: -64px -112px; }

.ui-icon-clock { background-position: -80px -112px; }

.ui-icon-disk { background-position: -96px -112px; }

.ui-icon-calculator { background-position: -112px -112px; }

.ui-icon-zoomin { background-position: -128px -112px; }

.ui-icon-zoomout { background-position: -144px -112px; }

.ui-icon-search { background-position: -160px -112px; }

.ui-icon-wrench { background-position: -176px -112px; }

.ui-icon-gear { background-position: -192px -112px; }

.ui-icon-heart { background-position: -208px -112px; }

.ui-icon-star { background-position: -224px -112px; }

.ui-icon-link { background-position: -240px -112px; }

.ui-icon-cancel { background-position: 0 -128px; }

.ui-icon-plus { background-position: -16px -128px; }

.ui-icon-plusthick { background-position: -32px -128px; }

.ui-icon-minus { background-position: -48px -128px; }

.ui-icon-minusthick { background-position: -64px -128px; }

.ui-icon-close { background-position: -80px -128px; }

.ui-icon-closethick { background-position: -96px -128px; }

.ui-icon-key { background-position: -112px -128px; }

.ui-icon-lightbulb { background-position: -128px -128px; }

.ui-icon-scissors { background-position: -144px -128px; }

.ui-icon-clipboard { background-position: -160px -128px; }

.ui-icon-copy { background-position: -176px -128px; }

.ui-icon-contact { background-position: -192px -128px; }

.ui-icon-image { background-position: -208px -128px; }

.ui-icon-video { background-position: -224px -128px; }

.ui-icon-script { background-position: -240px -128px; }

.ui-icon-alert { background-position: 0 -144px; }

.ui-icon-info { background-position: -16px -144px; }

.ui-icon-notice { background-position: -32px -144px; }

.ui-icon-help { background-position: -48px -144px; }

.ui-icon-check { background-position: -64px -144px; }

.ui-icon-bullet { background-position: -80px -144px; }

.ui-icon-radio-on { background-position: -96px -144px; }

.ui-icon-radio-off { background-position: -112px -144px; }

.ui-icon-pin-w { background-position: -128px -144px; }

.ui-icon-pin-s { background-position: -144px -144px; }

.ui-icon-play { background-position: 0 -160px; }

.ui-icon-pause { background-position: -16px -160px; }

.ui-icon-seek-next { background-position: -32px -160px; }

.ui-icon-seek-prev { background-position: -48px -160px; }

.ui-icon-seek-end { background-position: -64px -160px; }

.ui-icon-seek-start { background-position: -80px -160px; }
/* ui-icon-seek-first is deprecated, use ui-icon-seek-start instead */

.ui-icon-seek-first { background-position: -80px -160px; }

.ui-icon-stop { background-position: -96px -160px; }

.ui-icon-eject { background-position: -112px -160px; }

.ui-icon-volume-off { background-position: -128px -160px; }

.ui-icon-volume-on { background-position: -144px -160px; }

.ui-icon-power { background-position: 0 -176px; }

.ui-icon-signal-diag { background-position: -16px -176px; }

.ui-icon-signal { background-position: -32px -176px; }

.ui-icon-battery-0 { background-position: -48px -176px; }

.ui-icon-battery-1 { background-position: -64px -176px; }

.ui-icon-battery-2 { background-position: -80px -176px; }

.ui-icon-battery-3 { background-position: -96px -176px; }

.ui-icon-circle-plus { background-position: 0 -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-minus { background-position: -16px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-close { background-position: -32px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e { background-position: -48px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s { background-position: -64px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w { background-position: -80px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n { background-position: -96px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e { background-position: -112px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s { background-position: -128px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w { background-position: -144px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n { background-position: -160px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-zoomin { background-position: -176px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-zoomout { background-position: -192px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circle-check { background-position: -208px -192px; }

.ui-icon-circlesmall-plus { background-position: 0 -208px; }

.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus { background-position: -16px -208px; }

.ui-icon-circlesmall-close { background-position: -32px -208px; }

.ui-icon-squaresmall-plus { background-position: -48px -208px; }

.ui-icon-squaresmall-minus { background-position: -64px -208px; }

.ui-icon-squaresmall-close { background-position: -80px -208px; }

.ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical { background-position: 0 -224px; }

.ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal { background-position: -16px -224px; }

.ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical { background-position: -32px -224px; }

.ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal { background-position: -48px -224px; }

.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se { background-position: -64px -224px; }

.ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se { background-position: -80px -224px; }


/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Corner radius */

.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}

.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr {
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}

.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl {
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}

.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
}

/* Overlays */

.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #aaaaaa /*{bgColorOverlay}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) /*{bgImgUrlOverlay}*/ 50% /*{bgOverlayXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgOverlayYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgOverlayRepeat}*/;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=30)/*{opacityOverlay}*/;
    opacity: .3;
}

.ui-widget-shadow {
    -khtml-border-radius: 8px/*{cornerRadiusShadow}*/;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px/*{cornerRadiusShadow}*/;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px/*{cornerRadiusShadow}*/;
    background: #aaaaaa /*{bgColorShadow}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) /*{bgImgUrlShadow}*/ 50% /*{bgShadowXPos}*/ 50% /*{bgShadowYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgShadowRepeat}*/;
    border-radius: 8px/*{cornerRadiusShadow}*/;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=30)/*{opacityShadow}*/;
    margin: -8px /*{offsetTopShadow}*/ 0 0 -8px/*{offsetLeftShadow}*/;
    opacity: .3;
    padding: 8px/*{thicknessShadow}*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that the CSS for the datepicker affects the accordion layout/usability? Easiest solution is to wrap each item in it's own div with a specific class then use that class to tailor the CSS.